# Help with this question from my textbook

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Hello I've been battling with this particular question from my statistics textbook for hours. Can someone kindly help with this.

Note: it is not an assignment question. I'm solving all questions in the textbook.

Thanks.

Suppose a professor is carrying out a statistical research in New York and found out that the duration of marriages without the consent of parents have been found to be normally distributed with mean of 10 years and standard deviation of 3 years.

a. Find the probablity that a single marriage of this nature would last longer than 18 years.

b. What is the probability that the mean of a simple random sample of 50 such marriages would not last longer than 9 years?

c. The probability is 0.80 that the mean of a random sample of 80 such marriages is between X₁ and X₂. Find X₁ and X₂ using symmetrical limits about the mean

Comment: For part (a), doesn't your book include a formula for how to calculate probabilities involving normal distributions? Look up error function or erf or erfc. For (b) and (c), note that if $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are i.i.d. normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)/n$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: It may help to point out that for (c), they seem to be asking for $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be equally distant on opposite sides of the mean $10$.  For instance, the range $6$ to $14$ would qualify, if there were exactly $80$ percent of the population in that interval, because $6$ and $14$ are both $4$ away from $10$, on opposite sides.  (There isn't exactly $80$ percent, but it's in that ballpark.)

Comment: Could you edit the title of your question so that when someone reads it they will have an idea of what the question is about? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For part a), all you need to do is integrate the normal distribution curve (with the specified mean and standard deviation) over the interval $(18,\infty)$ using the error function, technology, or even by standardizing the data and using tables.

Part b) and part c) both rely on the fact that a simple random sample of means from a normal distribution will also be normally distributed with the same mean $\mu$ but rather a standard deviation of $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Thus for b) you can integrate the normal curve (using the modified standard deviation) over the interval $(-\infty,9)$ to obtain the required probability.

In c), you can use the fact of symmetrical limits to solve the equation $\int_{\mu-k}^{\mu+k} f(x)\,dx=0.8$ for $k$, where $f(x)$ is the normal curve with your mean and modified standard deviation. In this case, $\mu-k$ would represent $X_1$ and $\mu+k$ would represent $X_2$.

Comment: I stand corrected; I mistakenly was thinking that the effect on the mean and standard deviation was part of the CLT. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: One more note, I believe in part (c) the intent is that the integral should be taken from $\mu-k$ to $\mu+k$. Looks good otherwise.

Comment: @Bungo thanks for the answers. I totally understand the a and b part now. The c part is a little bit fuzzy. Will X₁ and X₂ be the same value

Comment: @EthanHunt I got 10.43 and 9.57 for the part c. Is this right please?

Comment: @johnscott Yes, those are the correct values for $X_1$ and $X_2$.